# Coercing A Column to Become the Row Identifier

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I would like to coerce a column to become the row identifier. My current data structure should be attached but I will describe it anyway.

```
   Animal   Protein   Fat
1   Dog       4        2
2   Sheep     5        8
3   Horse     9        10
4   Lion      12       7
```

Currently each row is identified by 1,2,3,4.  I would rather have each row identified by Animal.  Is there a way to do this in R.

[[image]

Comment: `newdata = data.frame(olddata , row.names = "Animal")`, although this does seem a less useful way to hold your data

Comment: @user20650, playing devil's advocate, at least one advantage in the given situation (if not mentioned by the user and conditional on the data in columns 2 through J being numeric) is that the data.frame could be converted into a matrix, which sometimes has advantages in modeling and speed in manipulation.

Comment: fair point @imo

Answer (score 1):

You can set the row names with `row.names`

```
Animals = read.table(text="Animal   Protein   Fat
1   Dog       4        2
2   Sheep     5        8
3   Horse     9        10
4   Lion      12       7",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

row.names(Animals) = Animals$Animal
```

If you want to get rid of the (now spurious) Animal column

```
Animals = Animals[,-1]
Animals
      Protein Fat
Dog         4   2
Sheep       5   8
Horse       9  10
Lion       12   7
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `column_to_rownames` from `tibble`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%  
     column_to_rownames('Animal')
#       Protein Fat
#Dog         4   2
#Sheep       5   8
#Horse       9  10
#Lion       12   7
```